# Javascript Parameter format

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I don't understand the difference between these two functions:

```
function animal({ cat }){
  return cat 
}

function animal(cat){
  return cat 
}
```

why use one over the other? Is there an advantage?

Comment: Did you try running the code? They don't do the same thing...

Comment: The first is using [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and the other is returning the full cat object.

Answer (score 0):

The first function will return the property `cat` from the object which is passed in as it is using  [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). The second will return the full object `cat` which is the objected that was passed in.

For example, the first function is equivalent to:

```
function animal(catObj){
  return catObj.cat; 
}
```

Meaning that when you call `animal()` you pass through an object which has the property `cat` within it.

eg:

```
const myCatObj = {
  cat: true,
  dog: false,
  name: "Meow"
}

animal(myCatObj); // retruns true
```

So, if we're looking at the first function, this will extract the `cat` property and return `true`.

Your second function will simply just return the entire object passed into the function. So if we passed through `myCatObj` we would get the same contents within `myCatObj` as an output.

So, to answer your question, both are used to perform different sorts of functions, so they each have their own advantages in certain scenarios.

Answer (score -1):

calling those two functions

`animal({cat:9});` returns `9`

`animal(9);` returns `undefined` since the number 9 does not have a cat property (everything is an object in js)

we use the 1st function when we want to know about the cat property of an object

we use the second one when we want to call an object directly